# BeautifulSoup 3 find tags with different attributes

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I am new to python and BeautifulSoup. I am trying to scrape an Indian news site. I use BeautifulSoup 3 and python 2 because of a limitation. The website I try to scrape is http://www.madhyamam.com/kerala.

I am interested in extracting the 2 div tags mentioned below.

```html
<div class="col-xs-12"></div>
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-8"></div>
```

I tried the below options based on some posts in stackoverflow.

```html
feedArtList = mySoup.findAll('div', {'class' : 'col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-8', 'class' : 'col-xs-12'})
# Returns only the div tags for col-xs-12
```

```html
feedArtList = mySoup.findAll('div', {'class' : re.compile('col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-8' | 'col-xs-12')})
# Returned an error "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'str'"
```

Appreciate if somebody can help me with the issue or provide pointers on how to resolve.

Comment: Bs3 is broken and full of bugs, how are you in a situation where you cannot upgrade? Using python2 would not be the reason.

Comment: Bs3 is packaged along with another python program that I use viz. calibre. I am trying to create a calibre recipe which internally uses python and only has Bs3 implemented in it according to what I was able to figure out.